# For $n \in \Bbb N$ define $f(x) = \frac {x^n} {1+x^n}$, then $f(x)$ converges on $[c, \infty]$ for $c>1$

Tags: real-analysis

For $n \in \Bbb N$ define $f(x) = \frac {x^n} {1+x^n}$, I am trying to show that on the interval $[c, \infty]$ where $c > 1$ that $f(x)$ converges uniformly.

I have to show that for $\epsilon >0$ that there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$

$|\frac {x^n} {1+x^n} - 1| < \epsilon$, but what confuses me is that it would need to hold for all $x$ in the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof works.  Note that for $0<\epsilon<1$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}-1\right|&=\frac{1}{1+x^n}\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{1+c^n}\\\\
&<\epsilon \tag 1
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>\frac{\log(1-\epsilon)-\log(\epsilon)}{\log(c)}$.  And for $\epsilon\ge 1$, the inequality in $(1)$ holds trivially.

---

Note that the convergence is not uniform on $(1,\infty)$ since for $\epsilon=2/3$, we can take $x=(1/2)^{1/n}$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{1}{1+x^n}=\frac{1}{1+1/2}=2/3=\epsilon$$

Comment: Why not $n >( log(1/\epsilon - 1))/ (log(c))$

Comment: They are the same. $\log(a/b) = \log a - \log b$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. ok great.

Answer (score 1):

The $M$-test is for series.

If $x \ge c > 1$, then  $$ \left| \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n} - 1 \right| = \frac{1}{1 + x^n} \le \frac{1}{1 + c^n}.$$
Since the last term $\dfrac{1}{1 + c^n} \to 0$ and is independent of $x$, the convergence is uniform.